# orphaned UILocalNotification - confirmed

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app I am working on with allows the user to set and remove UILocalNotifications. In the course of developing this I have added and removed UILocalNotifications for testing and it seems to be working.

However I am seeing strange behavior where, after deleting my app from the device and running it again *without* setting any notifications, I will get a UILocalNotification. This notification was not set in this fresh install (checked through adding a breakpoint in my notification setup method).

Is it possible that I have an orphaned UILocalNotification from a previous install (yes, it seems highly unlikely to me too).

I've tried debugging this by setting the notification `alertBody` to something specific to each new install but this unique string doesn't get displayed in the alert. For example:

```
notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert for: %@", alertName];
```

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before?

**Update:** Just confirmed orphaned UILocalNotifications: deleted the app from the device and ran the code below in my rootViewController on `viewDidAppear`. I get the following output in the Console:

> ```
> 2013-03-14 14:20:07.439 TestApp[16606:907] found alert: uigffhy
> 2013-03-14 14:20:07.444 TestApp[16606:907] found alert: uigffhy
> ```

Where this user was from some previous install. Ugh.

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

for (UILocalNotification *notif in notificationArray) {
    NSDictionary * info = notif.userInfo;
    NSString * name = [info objectForKey:@"sequenceName"];
    NSLog(@"found alert: %@", name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect if it's a fresh install (using `NSUserDefaults`) and do the following in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Makes me wonder though: isn't this a bug, since all app data should be removed when the app is removed.

Comment: From this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923028/uilocalnotification-fires-after-reinstalling-the-app

According to Apple, this is not a bug (I filed a bug report). The system retains the UILocalNotifications for uninstalled apps for 24 hours just in case the user deleted the app by accident, and restores the said UILocalNotifications if the app is re-installed within that time frame.